# What does jQuery's $ mean in this function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the difference in `$`?

**Question:**

What does `$` mean in the next example?

**JS:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    console.log('loaded');
});

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    console.log('loaded');
});
```

Can someone explain to me what is the difference between these 2 functions?

Thank you in advance

Comment: It is simply argument name.

Comment: this particular ( $ ) argument have some function/meaning in jQuery ? Or it is just argument named '$'.

Comment: Read the documentation. See the section: [Aliasing the jQuery Namespace](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: It's the global jQuery Object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`$`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) is normally the name of the jQuery constructor. That is to say, it is the name of a function that you call every time you want to make a jQuery object.  For instance:

```
$('div')
```

It is normally a global variable, which means it is available throughout the page's Javascript. There is another variable `jQuery`, which normally points to exactly the same thing.

```
console.log($ === jQuery); // true
```

However, it is *possible* to set `$` to something else. Perhaps you want to use `$` to mean something different in your code. Or perhaps you're using Prototype as well, which also uses the `$` symbol to point to a function.

This is why the [`jQuery.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict) method exists: it stops `$` referring to `jQuery`.

However, many authors prefer to use `$` to refer to the jQuery constructor, because it's much more concise and readable. jQuery provides a helpful feature that allows them to do this easily.

When you do `jQuery(document).ready(function()`, you are assigning an event handler. The function will be run when the event is fired. What we can do is reassign `$` to refer to jQuery *solely in the scope of that callback function*. This is aided by jQuery: every `$(document).ready` callback function is called with the `jQuery` constructor as the first argument, so you can use whatever name you choose within the function.

For instance:

```
var $ = 'apples';

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('div'); // causes an error: "TypeError: string is not a function"
});

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('div'); // works fine
});
```

This functionality is documented in the jQuery API for the [`ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) method, in the section entitled "Aliasing the jQuery Namespace".

Answer (score 2):

It's just the name of an argument.

See the [documentation for ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

> the handler passed to the .ready() method can take an argument, which is passed the global jQuery object